# Should Django-specific Python packages require Django?

Tags: python, django

I was looking at the [setup.py file for django-mailbox](https://github.com/coddingtonbear/django-mailbox/blob/master/setup.py#L57) and noticed that Django is not listed in `install_requires`. Django is imported in many different places in the package, so the django-mailbox package definitely requires Django.

Is Django not listed so the desired version of Django can be chosen beforehand? More specifically, is it a best practice to not require Django when developing a Django-specific package?

... or is this just a bug in django-mailbox?

Comment: It is *"advisable"* to do so. But none of us going to use *django-mailbox* without installing Django, are we?

Comment: I would treat it as a bug. It definitely should list Django as a dependency.